How to create a Virtual layer with point geometry and count repetitions
From a table with the following fields:



CODE1
CODE2
XCOORD
YCOORD




162
6605548EG7180N0001SF
418596,65
4620206,74


196
6604802EG7180S0001SX
418477,91
4620364,53


196
6604802EG7180S0001SX
418477,91
4620364,53


196
6604802EG7180S0001SX
418477,91
4620364,53


271
6605571EG7180N0001MF
418505,91
4620339,07


347
6605569EG7180N0001OF
418513,25
4620328,71


415
6605566EG7180N0001TF
418523,92
4620312,81


663
6604801EG7180S0001EX
418473,32
4620369,35


713
6604832EG7180S0002KM
418593,37
4620192,22


713
6604832EG7180S0002KM
418593,37
4620192,22


1128
6605547EG7180N0009AX
418603,38
4620193,32


1626
6604806EG7180S0001WX
418491,55
4620344,03


1695
6604830EG7180S0001XX
418583,67
4620205,61


1757
6605551EG7180N0001SF
418572,92
4620238,87


1757
6605551EG7180N0001SF
418572,92
4620238,87


1757
6605551EG7180N0001SF
418572,92
4620238,87


1757
6605551EG7180N0001SF
418572,92
4620238,87


1757
6605551EG7180N0001SF
418572,92
4620238,87


1757
6605551EG7180N0001SF
418572,92
4620238,87



I would like to create a virtual layer that does the following:
1- Group by the field 'CODE1'
2- Draw a point geometry at coordinates 'XCOORD' and 'YCOORD'
3- Count the number of repetitions by 'CODE1'
For example, for the resulting layer with point geometry, the table structure would be:



CODE1
CODE2
REPETITIONS




162
6605548EG7180N0001SF
1


196
6604802EG7180S0001SX
3


271
6605571EG7180N0001MF
1


347
6605569EG7180N0001OF
1


415
6605566EG7180N0001TF
1


663
6604801EG7180S0001EX
1


713
6604832EG7180S0002KM
2


1128
6605547EG7180N0009AX
1


1626
6604806EG7180S0001WX
1


1695
6604830EG7180S0001XX
1


1757
6605551EG7180N0001SF
6




You can use group by and count...
Go to the menu Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer... and enter the following query. Replace 1234 by your CRS ID.
SELECT code1, code2, count(*) as REPETITIONS, MakePoint(XCOORD,YCOORD,1234) as geometry
FROM myLayer
GROUP BY code1, code2

PS: Depending how the primary key is defined, you might have to use min(xcoord) and min(ycoord)

Could you give more details in which conditions it is recommended to use the functions min(xcoord) and min(ycoord), and could you add an example of the virtual layer query?

https://www.sqlite.org/quirks.html#aggregate_queries_can_contain_non_aggregate_result_columns_that_are_not_in_the_group_by_clause

Very useful, thank you
